# Read the tag content of Open Graph from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to read the tag content of og:image in the page header from code behind. How can I do that?

```
<meta property="og:image" name="og:image" content="mydomain.com/testing.jpeg" />
```

The string that I want to read from code behind is "mydomain.com/testing.jpeg".

Answer (score 1):

The head tag for aspx pages has the 'run at server' attribute set so you can programmatically access it from code.

To solve your specific question:

```
        var stuffWrapper = this.head.Parent.Controls[0];//("og:image");
        var stuff = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta)stuffWrapper).Content;
```

Normally you would use the `.FindControl` method on your controls collection to get programmatic access to the aspx tag.  Not sure what 'dotted-notation-path' you would have to discover to allow the `.FindControl` method to work.

So, in this specific case you will have to know what zero-indexed location your meta tag is within the head tag.  And if you reorder the tags in the header in the future your code will behave badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate the meta tags from code behind. That way you have full control.

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "og:image";
meta.Content = "mydomain.com/testing.jpeg";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```